# приложение - менеджер проектов

Tags: jira, project-management, trello, менеджмент

Кто-нибудь знает нормальный менеджер проектов с нормальным ui/ux мобильным приложением?

Требуется:

- ограничение прав
- множественное назначение в одной задаче
- офлайн работа
- 200+ юзеров (над одним проектом могут работать 10-15)
- русский интерфейс
- хранение (или быстрый доступ к онлайн хранилищу - google drive, etc)
  файлов (прикрепление из диалога по проекту)
- уведомление смс/push за какой-то срок (желательно настраиваемый) до истечения даты окончания

Что уже смотрел:

- редмайн

  Есть всё, но плохой ui/ux. Web mobile выглядит плохо, все мобильные приложения так или иначе ограничены. Есть мысль допилить react приложение как PWA. Не знаю, стоит ли
- wrike - тоже не полная функциональность на мобилке
- trello - нет ограничения прав, не входящий в задачу юзер из команды может менять её менять (если входит в проект)
- **jira**

  200+ человек выходит дорого. расскажите, можно ли формировать несколько команд по 10-15 человек в серверной версии, покупая лицензию на 20 человек?

---

*Если вопрос не по теме сайта, прошу его удалить. В правилах подобного не нашел*

Comment: Можно YouTrack от JetBrains посмотреть, но не знаю как у него с мобильным приложением.

Comment: [3 000 Евро](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/youtrack/buy/#standalone?billing=yearly)  = 208k р. Дорого

Comment: Ну вы хотите **хороший** инструмент, чтобы управлять командой **200+ человек**, и при этом хотите платить за это примерно **ничего**? Такого не бывает.

Comment: Допустим, деньги найдут. Попробовал андроид приложение, русского перевода там не нашел.